# Async implementation of Custom Commands in VSIX

Tags: c#, visual-studio, async-await, vsix, mpf

When you add a template custom command in a VSIX project, the scaffolding code that Visual Studio generates includes the following general structure:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="GenerateConfigSetterCommand"/> class.
    /// Adds our command handlers for menu (commands must exist in the command table file)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="package">Owner package, not null.</param>
    /// <param name="commandService">Command service to add command to, not null.</param>
    private GenerateConfigSetterCommand(AsyncPackage package, OleMenuCommandService commandService)
    {
        this.package = package ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(package));
        commandService = commandService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(commandService));

        var menuCommandID = new CommandID(CommandSet, CommandId);
        var menuItem = new MenuCommand(this.Execute, menuCommandID);
        commandService.AddCommand(menuItem);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function is the callback used to execute the command when the menu item is clicked.
    /// See the constructor to see how the menu item is associated with this function using
    /// OleMenuCommandService service and MenuCommand class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Event sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Event args.</param>
    private void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
        
        // TODO: Command implementation goes here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the singleton instance of the command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="package">Owner package, not null.</param>
    public static async Task InitializeAsync(AsyncPackage package)
    {
        // Switch to the main thread - the call to AddCommand in GenerateConfigSetterCommand's constructor requires
        // the UI thread.
        await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(package.DisposalToken);

        OleMenuCommandService commandService = await package.GetServiceAsync((typeof(IMenuCommandService))) as OleMenuCommandService;
        Instance = new GenerateConfigSetterCommand(package, commandService);
    }
```

Note that the framework-provided `MenuCommand` class takes a standard synchronous event-handling delegate with the signature `void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)`. Also, judging by the presence of  `ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread()`, it seems pretty clear that the body of the `Execute` method will indeed be running on the UI thread, which means it would be a bad idea to have any blocking synchronous operations running in the body of my custom command. Or do *anything* very long running in the body of that Execute() handler.

So I'd like to use `async/await` to decouple any long-running operations in my custom command implementation from the UI thread, but I'm not sure how to correctly fit that into the VSIX MPF framework scaffolding.

If I change the signature of the Execute method to `async void Execute(...)`, VS tells me that there's a problem with the `ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread()` call:
[image: "Avoid throwing when not on the main thread while in an async or Task-returning method. Switch to the thread required instead."]

I'm not sure how to "switch to the thread required instead". Is that what the `await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(package.DisposalToken)` code in the `InitializeAsync` method is doing? Should I just copy that?

What about exception handling? If I allow the synchronous `void Execute()` handler to throw an exception, VS will catch it and show a generic error messagebox. But if I change it to `async void Execute()` then uncaught exceptions *won't* be raised on the thread which invoked the `Execute`, and may cause a more serious problem elsewhere. What's the correct thing to do here? Synchronously accessing `Task.Result` to rethrow exceptions in the correct context seems like a canonical example of the [well-known deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Should I just catch all exceptions in my implementation and display my own generic message boxes for anything which can't be handled more gracefully?

### EDIT to ask more specific question

Here's a fake synchronous custom command implementation:

```
internal sealed class GenerateConfigSetterCommand
{
    [...snip the rest of the class...]

    /// <summary>
    /// This function is the callback used to execute the command when the menu item is clicked.
    /// See the constructor to see how the menu item is associated with this function using
    /// OleMenuCommandService service and MenuCommand class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Event sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Event args.</param>
    private void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();

        // Command implementation goes here
        WidgetFrobulator.DoIt();
    }
}

class WidgetFrobulator
{
    public static void DoIt()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        throw new NotImplementedException("Synchronous exception");
    }


    public static async Task DoItAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        throw new NotImplementedException("Asynchronous exception");
    }
}
```

When the custom command button is clicked, VS has some basic error handling which shows a simple message box:

[image: basic error message box for synchronously-thrown exception]

Clicking Ok dismisses the message box and VS continues working, undisturbed by the "buggy" custom command.

Now let's say I change the custom command's Execute event handler to a naïve async implementation:

```
    private async void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Cargo cult attempt to ensure that the continuation runs on the correct thread, copied from the scaffolding code's InitializeAsync() method.
        await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(package.DisposalToken);

        // Command implementation goes here
        await WidgetFrobulator.DoItAsync();
    }
```

Now, when I click the command button, Visual Studio terminates, due to the unhandled exception.

**My question is:**
What is the best practice way to handle exceptions arising from an async VSIX Custom Command implementation, which leads to VS treating unhandled exceptions in *async* code the same way it treats unhandled exceptions in *synchronous* code, without risking a deadlock of the main thread?

Comment: There are a lot of questions here. have you checked out this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-provide-an-asynchronous-visual-studio-service?view=vs-2019

Comment: Just as a side comment for context, I will be using the MySqlConnector package in my custom command. The authors strongly recommend using its async methods rather than synchronous. (https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/best-practices/) That makes me keen to write the custom command using async/await rather than sync style.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't seen that the "Use an asynchronous service in a command handler" subheading in the article. I'd glossed over the article because I didn't think I needed to write a service. Will check it out.

Comment: I've read it, but it's very confusing! The step-by-step instructions talk about adapting synchronous Packages into AsyncPackages, but in VS2017 15.9.25, the synchronous Package template no longer seems to exist; it's AsyncPackage only. And the instructions for adapting a Custom Command to call an async service refer to methods which don't exist in the modern Custom Command template such as `MenuItemCallback()` which I _think_ is replaced by `Execute()` in the current template.

Comment: I've left feedback on the article to suggest it be updated to work with the new item templates that MS is now distributing. Hopefully I can scrape enough clues out of it to figure out the right way to proceed.

Comment: The article linked by @TheGeneral has sample code where the command's `MenuItemCallback()` method, equivalent to `Execute()`, does a fire-and-forget invocation of the async service. It calls the Task-returning service without `await`ing the result and does nothing to handle exceptions. VS survives the exception without terminating, but it seems that the exception goes completely unobserved in this case. I don't accept that as best practice.

Comment: You can always raise your own exception dialog, or rethrow  the exception on the UI thread, i believe there is an example of that in your original question (you could try it, it may work in a catch). If you are satisfied with your results, might be a good idea to write up an answer to this and mark it correct

Comment: Would you mind clarifying how to rethrow an awaited exception on the UI thread? I'm not sure how that works. That's what I thought my "naive async implementation" would do, but instead it just kills VS.

Comment: have you tried `try { .. } catch(..) { SwitchToMainThreadAsync(..) throw}` i am not sure this will work, but it might be worth a try

Comment: That behaves the same as my naive implementation: kills VS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The previously-accepted answer generates a compiler warning, VSTHRD100 'Avoid async void methods', which is some indication that it may not be fully correct. In fact the [Microsoft threading documentation has a rule to never define async void methods](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/threading_rules.md#rule-4-never-define-async-void-methods-make-the-methods-return-task-instead).

I think the correct answer here is to use the JoinableTaskFactory's RunAsync method.  This would look as in the code below.  [Andrew Arnott of Microsoft says](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/issues/447#issuecomment-481068451) 'This is preferable [to async void] both because exceptions won't crash the app and (more particularly) the app won't close in the middle of an async event handler (that might be saving a file, for example).'

There are a couple of points to note.  Although exceptions won't crash the app they just get swallowed, so if you want to display a message box, for example, you'll still need a try..catch block inside the RunAsync.  Also this code is reentrant.  I've shown this in the code below: if you click the menu item twice quickly, after 5 seconds you get two messageboxes both claiming they came from the second call.

```
    // Click the menu item twice quickly to show reentrancy
    private int callCounter = 0;
    private void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
        package.JoinableTaskFactory.RunAsync(async () =>
        {
            callCounter++;
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            string message = $"This message is from call number {callCounter}";
            VsShellUtilities.ShowMessageBox(package, message, "", 
                OLEMSGICON.OLEMSGICON_INFO, OLEMSGBUTTON.OLEMSGBUTTON_OK, OLEMSGDEFBUTTON.OLEMSGDEFBUTTON_FIRST);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation that describes the correct usage of the
`ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory` APIs is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/managing-multiple-threads-in-managed-code).

In the end, I did the following:

```
private async void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
         await CommandBody();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Generic last-chance MessageBox display 
        // to ensure the async exception can't kill Visual Studio.
        // Note that software for end-users (as opposed to internal tools)
        // should usually log these details instead of displaying them directly to the user.
        await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync();

        VsShellUtilities.ShowMessageBox(
            this._package,
            ex.ToString(),
            "Command failed",
            OLEMSGICON.OLEMSGICON_CRITICAL,
            OLEMSGBUTTON.OLEMSGBUTTON_OK,
            OLEMSGDEFBUTTON.OLEMSGDEFBUTTON_FIRST);
    }
}

private async Task CommandBody()
{
    // Actual implementation logic in here
}
```